# How to call a function by a pointer?

Tags: c++

I have some base class in which I store a pointer to a function from derived class. I need to call a function by its pointer from two places: from BaseClass and from derived class.

```
template < class T >
class BaseClass {
private:
    typedef void ( T::*FunctionPtr ) ();
    FunctionPtr funcPtr;
public:
    void setFunc( FunctionPtr funcPtr ) {
        this->funcPtr = funcPtr;
        ( this->*funcPtr )(); // I need to call it here also but it doesn't work
    }
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass < DerivedClass > {
public:
    void callMe() {
        printf( "Ok!\n" );
    }
    void mainFunc() {
        setFunc( &DerivedClass::callMe );
        ( this->*funcPtr )(); // works fine here
    }   
};
```

Error: left hand operand to -> * must be a pointer to class compatible with the right hand operand, but is 'BaseClass *'

Comment: you can't use `this` as the left side of `->*` because `this` has type `BaseClass<T>`, it does not inherit from `T`

Comment: @RyanHaining thanks for the explanation. Can you show me a piece of code how to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
( this->*funcPtr )();
```

is the wrong syntax to use to call `funcPtr` since the type of `funcPtr` is `void T::*()`.

You need to use:

```
( (static_cast<T*>(this))->*funcPtr )();
```

Comment: In the base class you may want to add `static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, "T does not derive BaseClass")` to make sure the `static_cast` is safe an that no one is misusing your pattern